# solr admin UI access restrict to security.json

Tags: solrcloud

how to restrict to security.json to all other user expect super admin

super admin has all admin access and service user have access to only collections

when service user(permission to only collectios) login to admin UI, able see security.json(which has all rules and users), how to I block security.json to service users

Answer (score 0):

-d '{
   "set-permission" : {"name":"admin-ui",
                     "collection":null
                     "path":"/admin/zookeeper",
                     "role":"dev"}
}'